# MacBook Pro 2019 13" RAM upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, upgrade, memory

My MackBook specifications are shown in the screenshot below:

I would like to upgrade my MacBook RAM from 8GB to 16GB. I have looked to apple spec related to my type of MacBook that I find at this link [MacBook Pro 2019 Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP795?locale=en_US)
and it shows it is upgradable to 16GB. But the screenshot says no for upgradeable memory, do I miss something?

The other thing if I can upgrade, Am looking to replace it with HyperX i.e.

```
HyperX 16GB (Kit of 2) 2133MHz DDR3L CL11 1.35V SODIMM HyperX Impact Laptop Memory HX321LS11IB2K2/16
```

I need expert advice on the above or any other suggestion to upgrade the RAM to 16GB. Or If anything I missed.

[image: my MacBook pro spec overview]

[image: current ram slot]

Answer (score 6):

The **RAM** is only configurable to **16GB** at the time of purchase, or replacement of the *system board*, as the **RAM** modules are soldered to the  *system board*.

Note in the cropped screen shot from [Mactracker](https://mactracker.ca) there are no *memory slots* and it states it's *on-board memory* and why you cannot easily upgrade it after purchase, other than to replace the *system board*.

[image]

Comment: Technically you could upgrade the RAM by replacing the entire motherboard, but that would also require reimaging the motherboard with a clone of the first so it’s totally not worth it. Better to just by a new computer and sell the existing at that point.

Comment: @Robin Whittleton, Had I said the only way to upgrade the **RAM** is at the time of purchase, then for sure someone would have added a comment that one could also upgrade the RAM by replacing the system board and is the primary reason why I included "or replacement of the _system board_" in my answer. I would hope that one uses common sense in determining the best way to go for themself. As the question was specific to upgrading the **RAM** on their existing **Mac** and my answer covered that I didn't feel the need to suggest they sell it and purchase a different computer.